# Aligning two buttons on the same line works, but not divs

Tags: html, css

I have a simple banner with a text and two buttons. Each one is inside one div. I want to replace the buttons with two `<div>`. When I try this the UI broke. This is my code

```
#wrapper {
            background-color: gray;
            display: flex;
            padding-left: 90px;
            padding-right: 90px;
        }
        #left {
            padding-top: 33px;
            padding-bottom: 33px;
            flex: 0 0 65%;
            height: 80px;
            line-height: 44px;
        }
        #right {
            padding-top: 45px;
            padding-bottom: 45px;
            flex: 1;
        }
        #button1 {
            height: 70px; 
            width: 240px; 
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        #button2 {
            height: 70px; 
            width: 128px;
        }

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <input type="button" value="More" id="button1">
            <input type="button" value="Ok" id="button2">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to change to buttons with normal divs. When I do that the buttons are not aligned anymore. Do you have an idea about the problem?

```css
  #wrapper {
   background-color: gray;
     display: flex;
   padding-left: 90px;
   padding-right: 90px;
  }
  #left {
   padding-top: 33px;
   padding-bottom: 33px;
     flex: 0 0 65%;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 44px;
  }
  #right {
   padding-top: 45px;
   padding-bottom: 45px;
     flex: 1;
  }
  #button1 {
   height: 70px; 
   width: 80px; 
   margin-right: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 70px; 
  }
  #button2 {
   height: 70px; 
   width: 80px;
            background-color: green;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 70px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
  </div>
  <div id="right">
   <div id="button1">More</div>
   <div id="button2">Ok</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It is happening because input element is an inline element while div is not.
so you only need to add is

div#button1, div#button2{display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inline-flex display for the right column

```
#right {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) using `align-items: center` on the parent `#wrapper` element will centre vertically all its children, therefore the absolute `height` declaration on `#left` is not needed anymore.

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
}

#left {
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  line-height: 44px;
}

#right {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  flex: 1;
}

#button1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
}

#button2 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="button1">More</div>
    <div id="button2">Ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In addition, you may prefer to remove the top and bottom `padding` properties of both elements and use it on the parent (to retain equal spacing for both), but this depends on your use-case.